# Im trying to access an array in a object, and the object is in array in Angular Js

Tags: angularjs

```
$scope.arrays= [
            {
                form:'Arrays accessing',
                name:["array1","array2","array3","array4"]
            },
```

I need to access the array1, array2, array3, array4 in name, I tried below code but i'm getting first array1 only

```
$scope.addField = {};
$scope.addField.types = $scope.arrays[0].name[0];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JS I would write `forEach`:

```
 $scope.arrays.forEach(function(value, index) {     
     for (var i = 0; i < value.name.length; i++) {
         $scope.addField.types.push(value.name[i]);
     }
 });
```

To represent $scope.addField.types in HTML you can use `ng-repeat`, like:

```
<li ng-repeat="type in addField.types"></li>
```

(But sure it will work if above mentioned loop you write into controller)

Comment: it looks too much code.. to access an object it is working $scope.arrays[0].form; for accessing an array why i need this much code

Comment: right, you have list into list, no way but write two loops, i'll try to make it shorter :), see now